# SQL Server WHERE clause : column IS NULL or column = parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The code snippet below is what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm having trouble making it work. If the parameter that gets passed into the procedure is null, I want to only return the rows with a `WHERE` clause `IS NULL`, but if there is a value, I want to return the rows that are equal to the value passed in. Dynamic SQL seems like it would work, but I'm curious if there's an easier way I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

```
PARAM:

@id varchar(10) = '123456789'

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE T
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @id IS NULL THEN (id IS NULL)
        ELSE id = @id
    END
```

Comment: Does SQL Server support `where id is not distinct from @id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic you want is:

```
WHERE (@id IS NULL AND id IS NULL) OR
      id = @id
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use a `CASE` **expression** like a `Case` (`Switch`) statement. Switches don't exist in T-SQL, and a `CASE` expression returns a scalar value not a boolean result.

Don't, however, use `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE`, use proper Boolean logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE (ID = @ID
   OR  (ID IS NULL AND @ID IS NULL))
```